# Want to randomly choose word from text file and instead printing everything from text file

Tags: java

I want the compiler to `randomly` choose a word from text instead of printing everything from a text file. Right now the code below is printing everything from the text file. I think there is something wrong with my `getWord` method because when I call the `getWord` method from the main function I get an `error`.

```
public class TextFile {

        protected static Scanner file;
        protected static List<String> words;


        public TextFile(){
            words = openFile();
        }

        private List<String> openFile() {

            //List<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>();

                try {
                    file = new Scanner(new File("words.txt"));

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    System.out.println("File Not Found");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("IOEXCEPTION");
                }

                return words;
        }

        public void readFile() throws FileNotFoundException {

            //ArrayList<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>();

            while(file.hasNext()){
                String a = file.nextLine();
                //Collections.shuffle(words);
                //String pickWord = words.get(1);
                //String[] a = 
                System.out.println(a);
            }
        }

        public void closeFile() {
            file.close();
        }

        public String getWord() {

            Random r = new Random(words.size());
            String randomWord = words.get(r.nextInt());
            //System.out.println(randomWord);

            return randomWord;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

            try {

                TextFile file = new TextFile();

                file.openFile();
                file.readFile();

                file.closeFile();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("IOEXCEPTION");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You kind of were working in the right direction, `ArrayList` and `Collections.shuffle` would have worked

Comment: It's printing every line because you have a 'System.out.println(a);' in the readFile method.  Also I see no call to the getWord method anywhere.

Comment: *"I want the compiler to randomly choose a word from text instead of printing everything from a text file."* .. well if you want your _compiler_ to do that, then you need to write your own one.

Answer (score 0):

in the openfile method you are retuning a "word" variable which is 
null assign value to the variable

the error is coming from the {getword();} because you are accessing 
properties of a null variable its a error

```
     public List<String> readFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
       while(file.hasNext()){
            String a = file.nextLine();
            words.add(a);
            System.out.println(a);
        }
       return words;
    }
```

inside the open file method at the return statement line call "return readfile();" and try ur code\

no need to call readfile method inside the main method

Answer (score 0):

You are getting exception while calling getWord method as it throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException` at line `String randomWord = words.get(r.nextInt());`.

PFB correction to `getWord` method:

```
public String getWord() {
    //You can use any approach..Random or Collections
    //Random r = new Random();      
    //String randomWord = words.get(r.nextInt(words.size()));

    Collections.shuffle(words);
    String randomWord = words.get(1);

    return randomWord;
}
```

Again you should populate `words` field correctly:

```
public void readFile() throws FileNotFoundException {

    words = new ArrayList<String>();

    while (file.hasNext())
        words.add(file.nextLine());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You don't need to use the getWord() method in the main. 
Also, create a constructor for the class:

```
public TextFile() {
}
```

Your openFile() method doesn't need to return string.

```
    private void openFile() {


          try {
                file = new Scanner(new File("words.txt"));

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("File Not Found");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("IOEXCEPTION");
            }
}
```

Here is your readFile() method:
  1)Read file
  2)Split a line of words into each word and put it in array
  3)Then, random word

```
public void readFile() throws FileNotFoundException {

    //  List<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>();


        while(file.hasNext()){


            String line = file.nextLine(); //read file one line at a time

            String[] parseWords = line.split(" "); //Parse what you read


            int index = new Random().nextInt(parseWords.length);

            String randW = parseWords[index];
            System.out.println(randW);

        }
    }
```

In your main method:

```
TextFile file1 = new TextFile ();

file1.openFile();
file1.readFile();
file1.closeFile();
```